# IA-32 x86 Assembly function definition convention?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

Why do we always do

```
 pushl  %ebp          # save the old base pointer
 movl   %esp, %ebp    # set ebp to the current esp
 movl %ebp, %esp
 popl %ebp
```

^this, when defining functions in assembly?

Below is my translation of some code without pushes and pops and esp register used to access variables.

```
asm(
    "_calculateA:;"
    "   movl 8(%esp), %eax;"
    "   andl 4(%esp), %eax;"
    "   ret;"
    );
```

It is much shorter and works fine, so what's the deal?

Comment: Let me be precise If a compiler is translating C then okay.... But if  I am translating it myself, and let's say a code is indeed really simple, I won't have the need to debug and yet it takes extra lines to write as well as slows down the execution time by microseconds.

I wonder whether it would be okay to omit these...

Comment: Like would it be okay to omit these conventional lines if I'm writing a code as simple as the sum of two numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's it thanks!